# What is a DRY way to package a pipenv project?

Tags: python, pypi, pipenv

I am using [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) for [a small project](https://github.com/winni2k/pycortex).  The code looks like it might be useful and I would like to distribute it through [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).  I cannot find any guidance on the pipenv web page or its github repo on how to accomplish this.

I could put the dependencies from my `Pipfile.lock` into the [`install_requires` section](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#install-requires) of a `setup.py`, but I cannot find a tool to do that automatically, and doing it by hand would not be DRY.

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: `install_requrements` can be generated dynamically and the file is JSON. You just need to write a function to produce the right list from it.

Comment: Cheers. I'll have a go at that and post my solution here ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

To support external git dependency and versions. I have updated winni2kk code a little.

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import json


def get_requirements_from_pipfile_lock(pipfile_lock=None):
    if pipfile_lock is None:
        pipfile_lock = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'Pipfile.lock')
    lock_data = json.load(open(pipfile_lock))
    retval = []
    for package_name, package_data in lock_data.get('default', {}).items():
        if package_data.get('file'):
            package_ref = f'{package_name} @ {package_data["file"]}'
        else:
            package_ref = f'{package_name}{package_data["version"]}'
        retval.append(package_ref)
    return retval


packages = find_packages('.', exclude=['*.test', '*.test.*'])
pipfile_lock_requirements = get_requirements_from_pipfile_lock()

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=packages,
    license='MIT',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    install_requires=pipfile_lock_requirements,
    python_requires=">=3.5",
)
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: include Pipfile.lock within the MANIFEST.in like:

include Pipfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick for me:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import json


def get_requirements_from_pipfile_lock(pipfile_lock=None):
    if pipfile_lock is None:
        pipfile_lock = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'Pipfile.lock')
    lock_data = json.load(open(pipfile_lock))
    return [package_name for package_name in lock_data.get('default', {}).keys()]


packages = find_packages('.', exclude=['*.test', '*.test.*'])
pipfile_lock_requirements = get_requirements_from_pipfile_lock()

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=packages,
    license='MIT',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    install_requires=pipfile_lock_requirements,
    python_requires=">=3.5",
)
```

Comment: Just a small comment, [according to the Creative Commons Org itself](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software), you should not use any CC license on software.

Comment: Lol, I totally agree. I think I must have copied that from somewhere.

Comment: Looks like I got it from the Hitchhiker's guide to packaging: https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Checkout the [hatch](https://github.com/ofek/hatch) project. It takes care of virtual envs for you and makes it easy to package and distribute projects on PyPI. I learned a lot about packaging from it.